# Getting italic Computer Modern numerals with Times Roman font elsewhere in math

Tags: fonts, computer-modern

I am typesetting a document in Times Roman (using `txfonts`). However, the digits (0123456789) when italicized (with `\textit{}` or `\emph{}`) do not have the same script-y look as they do in Computer modern. With Times, they merely look slanted.

Is there a way I can use the italic versions of digits from Computer Modern in my otherwise Times Roman document? [I would like to have them available as separate symbols, say `\eins`, `\zwei` etc., instead of overwriting the default numbers.] I use script digits for a few purposes, including section headings, characteristic functions of sets (`\mathord{\textit{1}}_A`), power classes of sets (`\mathord{\textit{2}}^\varOmega`).

Comment: you should be using `\mathit` not `\textit` then you may get what you ask for already if you are only using newtxtext and not newtxmath

Comment: unrelated but you don't need \mathord around \textit (or better, \mathit) such constructs are automatically mathord.

Comment: `\mathit{1}` doesn't seem to produce what I desire. `txfonts` sets the math mode in times too. So, `\mathit{1}` and `\textit{1}` are (visually) identical.

Comment: `\mathit` is the thing to use in any case `\mathit` gives a fixed font from the math setup, `\textit` will give you whatever italic font is current in that part of the text. and won't get smaller in subscripts unless amsmath is used.

Comment: Don't use `\it` in any case. It is long obsolete in LaTeX.

Comment: I assume you're using pdfLaTeX to compile your document. Is switching to LuaLaTeX an option for you?

Comment: @Mico, LuaLaTeX is definitely an option, though I'd prefer not to (if possible)...

Comment: @cfr, when I wrote `\it1`, `\it2`, I didn't mean the obsolete command. I was simply trying to define a new name for the symbols I desire without overwriting the existing symbols. `\qwertyuiop1`, `\qwertyuiop2` would suffice as well :-)

Comment: @sami.spricht.sprache Oh, I see. You can't use numbers in macro names, so I assumed you meant `\it 1` as that would be the same as `\it1`.

Comment: @cfr, my bad. Edited to avoid any ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

A comment up front: The `txfonts` package, which provides both text and math fonts, has been superseded for several years now by a pair of packages: `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`. I can see no good reason for using the `txfonts` package if the vintage of your TeX distribution is more recent than, say, 2012.

If you can at all switch to LuaLaTeX, it becomes very straightforward to handle almost any number of math fonts side-by-side within a single document. Indeed, for what you appear to have in mind, something like the following setup is entirely sufficient:

```
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}[Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
```

The "STIX Two" text and math fonts may be downloaded free of charge from https://sourceforge.net/projects/stixfonts/

A full MWE (the use of "old-style", proportional-width text-mode numerals is optional):

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}[Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

% macros for characteristic functions and power classes of sets
\newcommand\cfset[1]{\mathit{1}_{\mkern-1.5mu#1}}
\newcommand\pcset[1]{\mathit{2}^{#1}}

\begin{document}
0123456789abcdef   % text: oldstyle numerals, proportional width

$0123456789abcdef$ % math: lining style numerals, fixed width

$\mathit{0123456789abcdef}$ "\mathit" automatically uses Latin Modern glyphs

$\cfset{K}$ $\pcset{\varpi}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: So, I assume there's no way to get this done with pdfLaTeX. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @sami.spricht.sprache You could do it with pdfLaTeX, if you wanted to.

Comment: @sami.spricht.sprache - Is there something that's keeping you from adopting LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @Mico, Just the fact that I have never used it before, and I don't know the (non-technical) advantages or disadvantages of a switch. Plus, I usually have a set preamble, which will have to be modified; e.g., I use `fontenc` which can't be used in LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @sami.spricht.sprache - For the most part, the LuaLaTeX format is a superset of the (pdf)LaTeX format, meaning that (almost) every document that compiles fine under pdfLaTeX should compile equally fine under LuaLaTeX. LuaLaTeX recognizes only one input encoding -- utf8. Hence one should indeed not load the `inputenc` package -- nor, for that matter and as you've noted in the comment, the `fontenc` package -- if the document is to be compiled with LuaLaTeX. The `fontspec` package allows LuaLaTeX (and XeLaTeX) users to access system fonts in fairly natural way.